# How to pass variables into a graphql query?

Tags: graphql, remix.run

I am using the storefront API to create a headless e commerce site.  I am having an issue passing variables into the query - where if I hard code the values it seems to work but as soon as I try and pass variables into the query it fails and says

```
Argument 'lineItems' on InputObject 'CheckoutCreateInput' has an invalid value ([[object, Object]]). Expected type '[CheckoutLineItemInput!]'
```

I am pretty sure the problem has to do with the passing of the variables becuase I have tried most things - and come to this conclusion.

Here is the query and action function

```
export const createCheckout = async (items: IProductVariant[]) => {
  
  const query = `

  mutation {
    checkoutCreate(input: 
      lineItems:  ${items}
           
    }) {
      checkout {
         id
         webUrl
         lineItems(first: 5) {
           edges {
             node {
               title
               quantity
             }
           }
         }
      }
    }
  }
    
      `;



export const  action: ActionFunction = async ({request}) => {
  // get the form data from the POST

  const formData = await request.formData()

  const id = Array.from(formData.getAll('id'))


  const quantity = Array.from(formData.getAll('quantity'))

  let items = id.map((item , idx) => {
    const newObj: IProductVariant  = {}
    newObj["variantId"]  = item as string
    newObj["quantity"] = Number(quantity[idx]) as number
    return newObj
  })

  const res = await createCheckout(items)

  return {res}

}
```

I think i need to modify the query to take a variable ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, this isn't possible. You would have to ensure that that node itself only returns 5 items if you wanted to do that, or alternatively make another query to get the data you require.

Comment: But how do you do this if you are adding products to a cart ? need to add all the details from when the user clicks add to cart?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I'm not sure that's how you call the GraphQL end point.

https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-01/mutations/checkoutCreate

```js
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api';

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Storefront('your-development-store.myshopify.com', storefrontAccessToken);

// define your mutation (note how you define the input type first, then call
// the mutation with the input variable
const query = 
   `mutation checkoutCreate($input: CheckoutCreateInput!) {
      checkoutCreate(input: $input) {
        checkout {
          id
          webUrl
          lineItems(first: 5) {
            edges {
              node {
                title
                quantity
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`;

// define the input data (this is from the docs, pass what is needed here)
const input = {
   {
    "allowPartialAddresses": true,
    "buyerIdentity": {
      "countryCode": ""
    },
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "key": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "email": "",
    "lineItems": [
      {
        "customAttributes": {
          "key": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "variantId": ""
      }
    ],
    "note": "",
    "presentmentCurrencyCode": "",
    "shippingAddress": {
      "address1": "",
      "address2": "",
      "city": "",
      "company": "",
      "country": "",
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "",
      "phone": "",
      "province": "",
      "zip": ""
    }
  };

// this is where you call the API passing in the query and variables
const data = await client.query({
  data: {
    "query": query,
    "variables": {
      "input": input,
      "queueToken": queueToken
    },
  },
});
```